# How to format html files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-wtp

The XML formatting works perfect but not the html formatting. In fact if I use "cmd-shift-F" for a html file, it just left aligns almost everything. I've attached the before and after pictures.

[image: No eclipse html formatting applied]

[image: After eclipse html formatting applied]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I played around with HTML formatting preferences but had no luck. Note that the same document, if it is saved as xml will format perfectly.

I am using eclipse 3.6 with WTP plugin.

Comment: The HTML format looks ok for me. I don't see how is your format preference. Maybe you should add it.

Comment: yup, you're right. That's the default behavior for the HTML editor in Eclipse.
To me that's a bug that should resolved.

Comment: No, problem still exists with Indigo and Juno.  Not sure about Kepler.

Comment: Still an issue in 2018, I guess the best solution is to use a different tool

Answer (score 69):

go to `Window --> preferences --> Web --> HTML files --> Editor`.

In the Inline Elements section, select all the elements that you don't want eclipse to inline(continue with same line).

Click **Apply** and then **Ok**.
Now re format using `ctrl + shift + f`.

Comment: `CTRL+Shift+f` works for me in LiClipse, However, it removes some `xhtml` compatibility such as `<br />` it make it `<br>`

Comment: This path still exists in Eclipse Neon, thanks looking for this for a LONG time

Comment: span is not in the list but still is forced on one line :(

Comment: In 2018-12, auto format will not indent `head` and its child elements. Also doesn't indent `body`. By default, these elements are not declared as inline.

Comment: Same issue (for my POV it is not a normal thing to inline an input or a label in p for instance...) in Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0).
I don't understand why the default formater settings are such a mess...
Thanks for the path of the preferences.

Answer (score 2):

go to Window --> preferences --> Web --> HTML files --> Editor.

Make sure "Indentation Size" is not set to zero.

That's what did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/

You can specify your formatting preferences too: http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/?act=preferences

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Juno release seems to do a good job.  It doesn't handle  tags (that is the div tag that closes itself).  Not sure why anyone would use it but we have a project that has them sprinkled about, probably from some WYSISYG editor someone was using.

Comment: You mean it doesn't handle empty tags? An HTML formatter that didn't handle tags would be ... not an HTML formatter.

Comment: Using Juno, I don't see anything wrong with formatting of empty div tags. However, it does left-align everything that's not inside a body tag (i.e. the head and body tags are left aligned, despite being inside the html element, plus every item inside the head element). This isn't the way I like it, and I can find no option to change that.

Answer (score -3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works fine.

Just click on the source codes you want to format and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.