# Configure Eclipse formatter to add newline in front of h:panelGroup

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets

I can't figure out how to configure the Eclipse formatter so it formats my xhtml pages the way I want. I would like (e.g.) `<h:panelGroup>` on a new line.

I get:

```
<h:panelGroup ...>
     ...
</h:panelGroup> <h:panelGroup ...>
     ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

But I would like:

```
<h:panelGroup ...>
     ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup ...>
     ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911379/how-to-format-html-files-in-eclipse)?

> go to Window --> preferences --> Web --> HTML files --> Editor.
>
> In the Inline Elements section, select all the elements that you don't want eclipse to inline(continue with same line).
>
> Click Apply and then Ok. Now re formant using ctrl + shift + f.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've looked there. But h:panelGroup is not in the list so I cannot remove it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried  ctrl + shift + f. That's when newline that I want is taken away from me. Do you find h:panelGroup in your Inline Elements list?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. And when I use ctrl + shift + f, it automatically formats as your expectation. One question, can you check your Eclipse shortcut key configuration by go to Window > Preferences > Keys and check if your Eclipse configures Ctr + shift + f is binding?

Comment: ctrl + shift + f formats the code, as expected. It is just that it does not produce the format I want. Thank you Tuan Hoang for your efforts!

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for not helping you solving the problem :( Last information, my Eclipse version to answer you is Photon Release (4.8.0)